# Proving continuity using the epsilon definition,a specific case

Tags: calculus

So, I was arguing with my friend about who is correct, I will not say what I said so in the case that I was wrong you will not know it :)

Anyway, the question is:

Prove that $f(x)= \frac1x$ is continuous at $x=2$ using the epsilon definition.

The function is defined at $x=2$ , $f(2)=\frac12$

Take $\epsilon > 0$

We need:

$$|f(x) - f(2)| < \epsilon\\
|\frac1x - \frac12| < \epsilon\\
-\epsilon < \frac1x - \frac12 < \epsilon\\
\frac12 - \epsilon < \frac1x < \epsilon + \frac12$$

Since $x=2$ and $1/2 \pm \epsilon$ is a neighborhood of $x=2$ the function is continuous at the point.

Is this fine or is there something missing ?

Comment: You need to have a $\delta$ somewhere. That is, you need to find a $\delta > 0$ so that for $|x -2| < \delta$, $|f(x) - f(2)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: I don't know we were taught that just saying |f(x) - f(c)| < ϵ is enough...
Does this delta change anything?

Comment: Yes, it is required to prove continuity using the definition of continuity.

Comment: When you were taught, you were taught the definition which includes $\delta$. Have a look at it.

Comment: The $\delta$ acts as a... relative measure of decrease in distance. That is, if $|f(x) - f(2)| < \epsilon$, then $|x - 2| < \delta$. $\epsilon$ doesn't necessarily _equal_ $\delta$ (although in some cases it makes sense for it to).

Comment: @AmagicalFishy No. If $|x-2|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(2)|<\epsilon$. What you wrote is incorrect.

Comment: Uhhh...So if on the final equation I move things around a bit and get this :

2/(1+2ϵ) < x < 2/(1-2ϵ)
Would this satisfy everything needed??

Sorry bout the formatting I just can't get this to work still lol

Comment: @newone No, what you need to show is that no matter what $\epsilon$ is, there is a finite distance (called $\delta$) so that as long as $x$ doesn't stray further away from $2$ than that, your inequality is _guaranteed_ to be satisfied (for instance, if $\epsilon = 1/3$ and $\delta = 1$ (that means that 1 < x < 3), you can see that close to the lowest allowed value for $x$, the inequality doesn't hold. So in that case $\delta$ wasn't strict enough. You need to show that you can _always find_ a delta that is strict enough.

Comment: Alright thanks all for the comments, I'm gonna talk with the teacher when I can, I believe we are just having semantic differences that is all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The continuity of function $f$ at some point $x$ requires for any given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for any $y$ such that $|y-x|<\delta$, we have $|f(y)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$.

So actually you are on the road, yet not reach the final. What you need is to find a $\delta$ so that the continuity condition holds. Could you keep on going now?

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have pointed out, you need to use $\delta$. Indeed, $\epsilon$ often depends on $\delta$.

Given any $\epsilon > 0$, let $\delta = \min\{1,2\epsilon\} > 0$. Now suppose that $|x - 2| < \delta$. Then since $\delta \leq 1$, we know that:
\begin{align*}
|x - 2| < 1
&\implies -1 < x - 2 < 1 \\
&\implies 1 < x < 3 \\
&\implies x > 1 \\
&\implies \boxed{|x| > 1}
\end{align*}
Hence, it follows that:
\begin{align*}
|f(x) - f(2)| &= \left| \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{2}\right| \\
&= \left| \frac{2 - x}{2x}\right| \\
&= \frac{|x - 2|}{2|x|} \\
&< \frac{|x - 2|}{2(1)} &\text{using the above boxed inequality} \\
&< \frac{2\epsilon}{2(1)} &\text{since $|x - 2| < \delta \leq 2\epsilon$} \\
&= \epsilon
\end{align*}
as desired. $~~\blacksquare$